# Meaning of infeasible model: unsuccessful solving for an IP model with binary variables

Tags: integer-programming, solver, binary-variable

For fun, I have modeled the [Union-closed sets conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union-closed_sets_conjecture) for a universe of a given size  into a problem with binary variables.

Each binary variable $x_k$ is the indicator of the set with elements being the positions of the digit $1$ in the binary representation of $k$. For example $x_{13}$ is $1$ if the set $\{0,2,3\}$ belongs to the family. Variables for sets with size less than $3$ are removed because the conjecture is already proven with those sets in the family. Also, if we have $n$ elements, $x_{2^n-1}$ can be replaced with a fixed $1$ because that is the universe. I have added constraints to guarantee that the family is union-closed and that it does not have an element in at least half of the sets. The latter is impossible if the conjecture holds, therefore I expect no solution to the IP problem.

For example, with $n=5$ elements, the model is this:

```
max: x7+x11+x13+x14+x15+x19+x21+x22+x23+x25+x26+x27+x28+x29+x30;
x7+x11-x15<=1;
x7+x13-x15<=1;
x7+x14-x15<=1;
x7+x19-x23<=1;
x7+x21-x23<=1;
x7+x22-x23<=1;
x11+x13-x15<=1;
x11+x14-x15<=1;
x11+x19-x27<=1;
x11+x25-x27<=1;
x11+x26-x27<=1;
x13+x14-x15<=1;
x13+x21-x29<=1;
x13+x25-x29<=1;
x13+x28-x29<=1;
x14+x22-x30<=1;
x14+x26-x30<=1;
x14+x28-x30<=1;
x19+x21-x23<=1;
x19+x22-x23<=1;
x19+x25-x27<=1;
x19+x26-x27<=1;
x21+x22-x23<=1;
x21+x25-x29<=1;
x21+x28-x29<=1;
x22+x26-x30<=1;
x22+x28-x30<=1;
x25+x26-x27<=1;
x25+x28-x29<=1;
x26+x28-x30<=1;
x7+x11+x13-x14+x15+x19+x21-x22+x23+x25-x26+x27-x28+x29-x30<=-2;
x7+x11-x13+x14+x15+x19-x21+x22+x23-x25+x26+x27-x28-x29+x30<=-2;
x7-x11+x13+x14+x15-x19+x21+x22+x23-x25-x26-x27+x28+x29+x30<=-2;
x7+x11+x13+x14+x15-x19-x21-x22-x23+x25+x26+x27+x28+x29+x30<=-2;
x7-x11-x13-x14-x15+x19+x21+x22+x23+x25+x26+x27+x28+x29+x30<=-2;
bin x7,x11,x13,x14,x15,x19,x21,x22,x23,x25,x26,x27,x28,x29,x30;
```

I have solved the problem with [LPSolve](https://sourceforge.net/projects/lpsolve/) and got:

```
Model name:  'LPSolver' - run #1
Objective:   Maximize(R0)

SUBMITTED
Model size:       35 constraints,      15 variables,          165 non-zeros.
Sets:                                   0 GUB,                  0 SOS.

Using DUAL simplex for phase 1 and PRIMAL simplex for phase 2.
The primal and dual simplex pricing strategy set to 'Devex'.

The model is INFEASIBLE
lp_solve unsuccessful after 10 iter and a last best value of -1e+030

MEMO: lp_solve version 5.5.2.11 for 32 bit OS, with 64 bit REAL variables.
In the total iteration count 10, 9 (90.0%) were bound flips.
There were 0 refactorizations, 0 triggered by time and 0 by density.
... on average 1.0 major pivots per refactorization.
The largest [LUSOL v2.2.1.0] fact(B) had 36 NZ entries, 1.0x largest basis.
The maximum B&B level was 1, 0.0x MIP order, with 0 nodes explored.
The constraint matrix inf-norm is 1, with a dynamic range of 1.
Time to load data was 0.002 seconds, presolve used 0.009 seconds,
... 0.012 seconds in simplex solver, in total 0.023 seconds.
```

The software states explicitly "The model is INFEASIBLE", as I expected, because there can't be any solution.

**QUESTION 1:** I suppose this can be considered a rigorous proof from a mathematical point of view: am I right?

The same result ("The model is INFEASIBLE") is obtained for $n \le 6$. But for $n = 7$ (and $n=8$) I get:

```
Model name:  'LPSolver' - run #1
Objective:   Maximize(R0)

SUBMITTED
Model size:     3122 constraints,      98 variables,        10031 non-zeros.
Sets:                                   0 GUB,                  0 SOS.

Using DUAL simplex for phase 1 and PRIMAL simplex for phase 2.
The primal and dual simplex pricing strategy set to 'Devex'.

Relaxed solution                  20 after        549 iter is B&B base.

lp_solve unsuccessful after 1661 iter and a last best value of -1e+030
lp_solve explored 6 nodes before termination

MEMO: lp_solve version 5.5.2.11 for 32 bit OS, with 64 bit REAL variables.
In the total iteration count 1661, 318 (19.1%) were bound flips.
There were 18 refactorizations, 0 triggered by time and 11 by density.
... on average 74.6 major pivots per refactorization.
The largest [LUSOL v2.2.1.0] fact(B) had 10967 NZ entries, 1.0x largest basis.
The maximum B&B level was 4, 0.0x MIP order, with 6 nodes explored.
The constraint matrix inf-norm is 1, with a dynamic range of 1.
Time to load data was 0.005 seconds, presolve used 0.008 seconds,
... 0.609 seconds in simplex solver, in total 0.622 seconds.
```

so in this case it just says "lp_solve unsuccessful".

**QUESTION 2:** Can this be considered a proof that there isn't any solution? Or the algorithm just "gave up"?

**Edit 2022-04-20**

For those who might be interested, I have found some [serious research](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.05947) somewhat related to the this post.

Comment: If I'm reading your model correctly (not a certainty), your last five constraints say that the number of set containing some element $i$ minus the number of sets not containing $i$ is at most -2, or equivalently there are at least two more sets without $i$ than there are sets with $i$. Why 2 and not 1?

Comment: Because I assume the family has a universe of $5$ elements, and it is union-closed, therefore $x_{31}=1$ (the universe indicator) and moving it to the right side of the inequality it gives $-2$.

Comment: And, to simplify, I just considered families without the empty set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be worth trying this alternative formulation, with your same $x_k$ variables (one for each of the $2^n$ subsets) and nonnegative slack variables $s_i$.  The problem is to minimize $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} s_i$ subject to
\begin{align}
x_k + x_\ell - 1 &\le x_{k \cup \ell} &&\text{for $k < \ell$} \tag1 \\
\sum_{k: i \not\in k} x_k - \sum_{k: i \in k} x_k + s_i &\ge 1 \tag2 &&\text{for $i\in \{0,\dots,n-1\}$} \\
\sum_{k \not= 0} x_k &\ge 1 \tag3  
\end{align}

Constraint $(1)$ enforces the union-closed property.
Constraint $(2)$ prevents element $i$ from appearing in at least half the sets if $s_i=0$.
Constraint $(3)$ avoids the trivial family that contains only the empty set.
(Note that I include all $2^n$ subsets and do not fix any $x_k$ variables to $0$ or $1$.)

If the LP relaxation has positive optimal objective value, the resulting optimal dual solution provides a short certificate that the conjecture is true.

Comment: Unfortunately, with slack variables, the result is $0$. So we can say nothing in this case?

Comment: If the objective value is zero, the solution should provide a counterexample to the conjecture. Does it?

Comment: If the objective value is $0$ and the $x$ variables take integer values, you have a counterexample.  Otherwise, you can't conclude anything.

Comment: Wait, I must retry, I didn't consider the empty set in Rob Pratt formulation, I have to check it again.

Comment: I think I have to replace $\ldots<=-2$ with $\ldots-s_i<=-1$ in my inequalities right?

Comment: Yes, $\dots -s_i \le -1$.

Comment: Rethinking about it, I think that $\ldots-s_i<=-2$, since I consider $x_{31}=1$ and $x_0=0$ in my "simplification". Thus we have $0$ objective value with non-integer $x_i$, and we can't conclude anything.

Comment: $\dots \le -2$ would be appropriate if you *omitted* $x_{31}.$ Rob's model includes it. You could fix $x_{31}=1,$ but there is no need to.